# Bijection between $P(\mathbb{N})$ and set $\{f | f:\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

> I need to find a bijection between the power set $P(\mathbb{N})$ and the set of functions $J=\{f|f:\mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}\}$

I considered the map $g:P\to J$ as $g(A)=f $ where $f$  is a function who is mapping $A$ to {0} and $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ to ${1}$, then i think this will be a required bijection!

Comment: That sounds right! Now why is it injective and surjective?

Comment: injective because if $A\ne B$ then their images will be different

Comment: sorry i've edited it now

Comment: And now that I know for sure what was intended, I can agree with @Ian: your map $g$ is correct, though you do still have to show that it’s a surjection. What you’re doing, by the way, is mapping each $A\in\Bbb N$ to $\chi_A$, the [*indicator function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $A$.

Comment: for any $f\in J$ ,let $A$ be subset of $\mathbb{N}$ consisting of all elements which are being mapped to $0$ by $f$ then $g(A)=f$ thus $g$ is surjective!

Comment: You’ve got it; if you want, you could write up those two comments of yours as an answer, and (after some hours — I forget how many) accept it. (This is a perfectly procedure; indeed, it’s encouraged.)

Comment: Actually $g(A)=1-\chi_A$, not $\chi_A$. But the bijection argument stands.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Actually, if you understand that $2^{\Bbb N}$ is in bijection with $P(\Bbb N)$, you have already answered this question. In other words, it is not a duplicate (though close).

Comment: @Brian: Encouraged, yes. Encouraged on duplicates? No. In fact it is encouraged to search for the question before posting it.